# Nlog.config - read only

Tags: c#, nlog

I installed Nlog from NuGet and tried to make some changes at NLog config. Unfortunately, that file is marked by a padlock. Also it is  placed out of the project catalogue (C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\nlog.config\4.7.13\contentFiles\any\any\NLog.config) and read-only. How should I correctly add that file to the project? Should I copy that and add it manually to the project?

Comment: The `Readme` for https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config tries to guide you in how to download manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nlog config file should be carefully located so your resulting build project files load it correctly. In the [documentation about the File Location info](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file) you see where the programs looks for the Nlog config file.

You can indeed include it in your project and set the property `Copy to Output directory` to `Copy if newer`